# When should I use react stateless component even if pure is always faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have read this great article. [Component Rendering Performance in React](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/component-rendering-performance-in-react-df859b474adc#.hs9k8djkg)

It seems like pure component is better performance than stateless, so if I don't care about the stateless component is simpler to write.

Should I just always use pure component instead stateless? Or there are something I get wrong?

In actually stateless component will always rerender when parent update right?

Comment: So, logically~ pure component is always not the wrong choise, only if some situations ( parent component can properly check shouldUpdate) then stateless can be a **not bad** choice ( just because of simplicity).

Answer (score 2):

Use stateless for leaf components, where you don't have any other custom component nested. Go with pure component for components higher up in the hierarchy.

In future versions, there maybe optimizations to allow some form of shouldComponentUpdate for stateless components as well. Follow [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5677). There're hoc based workarounds mentioned in there which you may like.